# Source of validation script in "Finish" screen

Tags: installation, install4j

Is it possible to distinguish the source inside the script that is written as content of the "Validation expression"?

This script gets triggered when any of the buttons is pressed: "Close", or "x" button in the screen frame.

I would like to have some additional handling if the "x" is the source (prevent launching of the app even if the default checkbox is triggered, do some custom stuff, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

For most screens, the validation script is only executed if the "Next" button is clicked. The one exception is the "Finish" screen or any screen that has the "Quit after screen" property selected. On those screens, closing the window is equivalent to clicking on the "Finish" button. Unfortunately, there is no way to distinguish between the two.

Some users choose to close installers on the last screen by closing the window and that could lead to a rollback if the distinction between "finish" screens and regular screens were not made.